# node js issue with resume-parser

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I am trying to use Node package for resume parser: https://github.com/perminder-klair/resume-parser

I am able to configure the project in my dev environment, but the code is not running due to error antiword in Windows 10.

I tries to find the solution and I got to know about http://www.winfield.demon.nl/#Windows

But for Windows, the link is not working: http://www-stud.rbi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~markus/antiword/

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: What' teh error you get ?

Comment: Please find the error <error> processing.js:78 () Error: antiword read of file named [[ resume.doc ]] failed: Error: Command failed: antiword -m UTF-8.txt "./files/resume.doc"

Comment: In the above mention question, I am able to find the solution but the link is not working for windows: http://www-stud.rbi.informatik.uni-frankfurt.de/~markus/antiword/